# Azure key vault - downloaded certificate not same as imported certificate

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I imported the following certificate into Azure keyvault

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgKlUqQnd/R70FJPSX
RLii3o7t0//f37fIVgU4fvI6SY6hRANCAAR5kpzf9KLuFMI1DYF+a/YXucDPdL+X
4zeflzyIDC0hjh149s+OUcRSfwoJbbvP/LgwZEPNdkzMGLOXnpoZ6JzO
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When I download the cert as pem, the private key is changed

```
az keyvault secret download --file "./text" --id https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/sample/6d5505d2d0cd4d2285c80dc5a259c61c
```

I got a different private key.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGiAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQgKlUqQnd/R70FJPSX
RLii3o7t0//f37fIVgU4fvI6SY6gCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAAR5kpzf9KLuFMI1
DYF+a/YXucDPdL+X4zeflzyIDC0hjh149s+OUcRSfwoJbbvP/LgwZEPNdkzMGLOX
npoZ6JzOoA0wCwYDVR0PMQQDAgCA
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Why is the private key changing? How can I get the same private key that I had imported?

Comment: What command did you use to import the secret? Certificates are backed by both keys and secrets. Depending on how you imported it, the content may be mangled.

Answer (score 0):

According to the az command you provided, you import certificate as azure key vault secret.

If so, the certificate content you sent will **be the same as the secret value you get**.

As I have test, when I import cert as secret. Then I retrieve the same secret value.

So, try to recreate a new secret and import again.

Comment: I want to import as certificate only,  exporting certificate does not give private key. Hence exporting as secret.

Comment: If you import as secret, it will not change.

Comment: Why does it change when you import as certificate?

Comment: I test in my site and import as certificate, it do not change.

Comment: not sure which certificate you have tested, but i tried the certificate I have mentioned in the question. and it changed on download.

Comment: There are advantages to storing the certificate as a certificate, such as automatic key rotation, using the keys to encrypt, decrypt, and more without leaving Key Vault (i.e. don't need to transmit the private key), etc. In some cases, you may not want a principal to have access to the private key, which certificates help avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Late but -- **it's the same key, encoded differently**

Your input is

```
$ openssl asn1parse <63646197.1 -i -dump
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 135 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :00
    6:d=1  hl=2 l=  19 cons:  SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim:   OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim:   OBJECT            :prime256v1
   27:d=1  hl=2 l= 109 prim:  OCTET STRING
      0000 - 30 6b 02 01 01 04 20 2a-55 2a 42 77 7f 47 bd 05   0k.... *U*Bw.G..
      0010 - 24 f4 97 44 b8 a2 de 8e-ed d3 ff df df b7 c8 56   $..D...........V
      0020 - 05 38 7e f2 3a 49 8e a1-44 03 42 00 04 79 92 9c   .8~.:I..D.B..y..
      0030 - df f4 a2 ee 14 c2 35 0d-81 7e 6b f6 17 b9 c0 cf   ......5..~k.....
      0040 - 74 bf 97 e3 37 9f 97 3c-88 0c 2d 21 8e 1d 78 f6   t...7..<..-!..x.
      0050 - cf 8e 51 c4 52 7f 0a 09-6d bb cf fc b8 30 64 43   ..Q.R...m....0dC
      0060 - cd 76 4c cc 18 b3 97 9e-9a 19 e8 9c ce            .vL..........
```

with the per-algorithm data for EC defined by SEC1 and (more conveniently) [rfc5915](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5915#section-3)

```
$ openssl asn1parse <63646197.1 -i -dump -strparse 27
    0:d=0  hl=2 l= 107 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :01
    5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING
      0000 - 2a 55 2a 42 77 7f 47 bd-05 24 f4 97 44 b8 a2 de   *U*Bw.G..$..D...
      0010 - 8e ed d3 ff df df b7 c8-56 05 38 7e f2 3a 49 8e   ........V.8~.:I.
   39:d=1  hl=2 l=  68 cons:  cont [ 1 ]
   41:d=2  hl=2 l=  66 prim:   BIT STRING
      0000 - 00 04 79 92 9c df f4 a2-ee 14 c2 35 0d 81 7e 6b   ..y........5..~k
      0010 - f6 17 b9 c0 cf 74 bf 97-e3 37 9f 97 3c 88 0c 2d   .....t...7..<..-
      0020 - 21 8e 1d 78 f6 cf 8e 51-c4 52 7f 0a 09 6d bb cf   !..x...Q.R...m..
      0030 - fc b8 30 64 43 cd 76 4c-cc 18 b3 97 9e 9a 19 e8   ..0dC.vL........
      0040 - 9c ce                                             ..
```

which as you can see does not have the optional context-0-tagged parameters field.

In contrast the output is

```
$ openssl asn1parse <63646197.2 -i -dump
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 162 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :00
    6:d=1  hl=2 l=  19 cons:  SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim:   OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim:   OBJECT            :prime256v1
   27:d=1  hl=2 l= 121 prim:  OCTET STRING
      0000 - 30 77 02 01 01 04 20 2a-55 2a 42 77 7f 47 bd 05   0w.... *U*Bw.G..
      0010 - 24 f4 97 44 b8 a2 de 8e-ed d3 ff df df b7 c8 56   $..D...........V
      0020 - 05 38 7e f2 3a 49 8e a0-0a 06 08 2a 86 48 ce 3d   .8~.:I.....*.H.=
      0030 - 03 01 07 a1 44 03 42 00-04 79 92 9c df f4 a2 ee   ....D.B..y......
      0040 - 14 c2 35 0d 81 7e 6b f6-17 b9 c0 cf 74 bf 97 e3   ..5..~k.....t...
      0050 - 37 9f 97 3c 88 0c 2d 21-8e 1d 78 f6 cf 8e 51 c4   7..<..-!..x...Q.
      0060 - 52 7f 0a 09 6d bb cf fc-b8 30 64 43 cd 76 4c cc   R...m....0dC.vL.
      0070 - 18 b3 97 9e 9a 19 e8 9c-ce                        .........
  150:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  cont [ 0 ]
  152:d=2  hl=2 l=  11 cons:   SEQUENCE
  154:d=3  hl=2 l=   3 prim:    OBJECT            :X509v3 Key Usage
  159:d=3  hl=2 l=   4 cons:    SET
  161:d=4  hl=2 l=   2 prim:     BIT STRING
      0000 - 00 80                                             ..
$ openssl asn1parse <63646197.2 -i -dump -strparse 27
    0:d=0  hl=2 l= 119 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :01
    5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING
      0000 - 2a 55 2a 42 77 7f 47 bd-05 24 f4 97 44 b8 a2 de   *U*Bw.G..$..D...
      0010 - 8e ed d3 ff df df b7 c8-56 05 38 7e f2 3a 49 8e   ........V.8~.:I.
   39:d=1  hl=2 l=  10 cons:  cont [ 0 ]
   41:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim:   OBJECT            :prime256v1
   51:d=1  hl=2 l=  68 cons:  cont [ 1 ]
   53:d=2  hl=2 l=  66 prim:   BIT STRING
      0000 - 00 04 79 92 9c df f4 a2-ee 14 c2 35 0d 81 7e 6b   ..y........5..~k
      0010 - f6 17 b9 c0 cf 74 bf 97-e3 37 9f 97 3c 88 0c 2d   .....t...7..<..-
      0020 - 21 8e 1d 78 f6 cf 8e 51-c4 52 7f 0a 09 6d bb cf   !..x...Q.R...m..
      0030 - fc b8 30 64 43 cd 76 4c-cc 18 b3 97 9e 9a 19 e8   ..0dC.vL........
      0040 - 9c ce                                             ..
```

which does have the context-0-tagged parameters field, which is redundant when used within PKCS8 as here; also at the PKCS8 level it has the [optional context-0-tagged attributes field](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208#section-5) containing one attribute with id KeyUsage and value digitalSignature. (OpenSSL displays the actual value field of the BITSTRING encoding, including the first octet which is reserved for 'unused bits' and here 00, so the encoded bits are 80, which is bit#0=digitalSignature.) This is technically redundant because it is already in the cert, but I guess Azure finds it convenient to have a copy here.

The actual key for cryptographic purposes is the curve-id, the private scalar "d" at offset 5 in the SEC1 data, and if present (which it is) the public point "Q" at context-1-tag in the SEC1 data, and you can confirm all three of those are the same in the output as the input.